# Wordpress Users Can Only Log In via Google

Tags: wordpress, google-apps

Given:
-Wordpress multisite/mu w/sub-domains.
-G Suite where users are managed.
-All sub-domains are for the same G Suite domain (think 'branches' of a store or bank).

Q: How can I restrict access to login to ONLY G Suite?

The dynamic creation of users who authenticate is in another question, but this one asks how I can provide only one means of authentication-on all sites in the network.

Answer (score 0):

The free version of Google Apps Login is heavily used on multisite installs, so you should be able to do what you want:

https://wp-glogin.com/glogin/

To manage users through automatic WP account creating based on authentication from your company's G Suite domain, you may be interested in the Premium/Enterprise version.

Anyway, please take a look and get in touch with the support address if you have any questions!